# List of interesting Quantitative Finance podcasts

Tags: big-list

Which podcasts are interesting to listen to for quants?

If you recommend one, why?

Answer (score 15):

Freakonomics usually has some interesting podcasts that cast light on misconceptions related to economic/finance statistics and beliefs.

[Grant's Current Yield](https://www.grantspub.com/podcasts.cfm) is another interesting podcast, done by the publisher of Grant's Interest Rate Observer, a publication that tracks the rates markets.

Answer (score 10):

I listened to a few episodes of AQR's [The Curious Investor](https://www.aqr.com/Insights/Podcasts) which cover a broad range of topics with the help of interesting guests.

Answer (score 9):

[Chat with Traders](https://chatwithtraders.com) is a series of interviews with traders and alike and some of them have a based trading strategies on quantitative methods. This Podcast is more about career. I have only listened to a few episodes.

[Flirting with Models](https://blog.thinknewfound.com/podcast/) is great podcast where in each episode the host and the guest discuss how the guest use specific financial models/methods in their daily work.

Otherwise I have good experience with some podcasts about Data Science and [here is a great list](https://realpython.com/data-science-podcasts/). If you spend five minutes you will be able to find many episodes about data science/machine learning application in Finance.

Answer (score 6):

[SSGA](https://www.ssga.com/global/en/our-insights/publications/inside-the-mind-of-a-quant-part-2.html) has some nice podcasts, mostly related to their products, but still. Unfortunately, they do not organize by category.

[Masters in Business](https://www.bloomberg.com/podcasts/masters_in_business) series also has some good podcasts. I recommend listening to these podcasts because they have different guests from different areas of Finance and it helps to catch up with what is going on.

Answer (score 4):

The *Curious Quant* with Michael Kollo. It's a fairly new podcast, but addresses the application of AI and alt data into finance and forecasting models, but in a non technical and thought provoking way. Anyways, that's the hope!

Answer (score 4):

The CQF institute just launched [QuantSpeak](https://www.cqfinstitute.org/content/quantspeak). I haven't listened yet but given their pedigree it should be interesting.

Answer (score 3):

I find more use tracking the derivatives pods than specific QF pods.

- Alpha Exchange
- Signals & Threads
- Flirting with Models
- Resolve Assets Gestalt University

Answer (score 2):

Jump Capital started a podcast in 2021: [The Jump off Point](https://podcast.jumpcap.com/public/88/The-Jump-Off-Point-8c500774).

Note that Jump Capital is the venture capital arm of Jump Trading, so it is more about that part of their business than it is about trading.

Answer (score 2):

Jane Street started a podcast in 2020: [Signals & Threads](https://signalsandthreads.com/).

This podcast focuses mainly on the tech side of things. It can also be appreciated by folks that don't write OCaml for a living ;)

Answer (score 2):

[Alpha Exchange](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/alpha-exchange/id1442284870)

The Alpha Exchange podcast is often interesting. Focus is more on derivatives than quant finance in general.